# Updating state in useEffect and the dependency array is the value of redux which is an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux

I have an array in redux. I am storing its value through useSelector in variable named masterStatusOptions.
Now masterStatusOptions is also one of the dependency array of my useEffect.
The logic that I have written in that use effect is updating the state variable which is correct.
When that use Effect is executed 1 time it is re rendering my component and now useSelector returns me the same array but I think the memory location changed. That is why again useEffect is called and since it is rerendering because state is changed my program goes into an infinite loop. How can I solve this?

```
const masterStatusOptions = lookupTypeData(useSelector((state) => state.lookup.lookup), 'user_status'); // This returns an array of lookup values
  const [statusOptions, setStatusOptions] = useState();
  useEffect(()=>{
    if(masterStatusOptions?.length){
      let masterArr = masterStatusOptions.filter((item) => item.priority !== 999);
      console.log(masterArr);
      setStatusOptions(masterArr); // Due to this rerender is triggered and masterStatusOptions value becomes a new memory address since it is returning an array and the whole code goes into infinite loop.
    }
  },[masterStatusOptions])
//LookupTypeData's code:
    export const lookupTypeData = (lookupData, type, idKey = "lookupId") => {
  console.log({lookupData})
  if (lookupData?.length) {
    let filtered = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < lookupData.length; i++) {
      const item = lookupData[i];
      if (item.lookupType === type && lookupData[i].isActive && lookupData[i].isVisible) {
        const newItem = {
          ...item,
          value: item[idKey],
          label: item.lookupDisplayValue ? item.lookupDisplayValue : item.lookupValue,
          disabled:item.isDisabled
        };
        filtered.push(newItem);
      }
    }
    filtered.sort((x, y) => x.priority - y.priority);
    console.log({filtered})
    return filtered;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this the only place you call `setStatusOptions`? I ask because if it is, this code should probably be written so that statusOptions is not a state, which would also fix your issue. I can show how to do that.

Comment: Yes this is the only place. statusOptions are basically the options for my dropdown and they can change basis the socket that I receive from backend

Comment: Please show the code for `lookupTypeData`.

Comment: Question updated with lookupTypeData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an infinite loop from arrays changing, but it's not the array in redux. That array is staying the same. Instead, the issue is that every time you render, you call lookupTypeData, which creates a new array. You will need to memoize that code so you only create the new array when the array in redux changes. For example:

```
const reduxArray = useSelector((state) => state.lookup.lookup);
const masterStatusOptions = useMemo(() => {
  return lookupTypeData(reduxArray, 'user_status');
}, [reduxArray]);
```

Then you can use your useEffect unchanged:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (masterStatusOptions?.length) {
    let masterArr = masterStatusOptions.filter((item) => item.priority !== 999);
    console.log(masterArr);
    setStatusOptions(masterArr);
  }
}, [masterStatusOptions]);
```

If masterStatusOptions isn't used anywhere else, you have the option to move it into the effect instead:

```
const reduxArray = useSelector((state) => state.lookup.lookup);
const [statusOptions, setStatusOptions] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
  const masterStatusOptions = lookupTypeData(reduxArray, "user_status");
  if (masterStatusOptions?.length) {
    let masterArr = masterStatusOptions.filter((item) => item.priority !== 999);
    console.log(masterArr);
    setStatusOptions(masterArr);
  }
}, [reduxArray]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided seems to be creating an infinite loop of re-renders because of the way you are using the masterStatusOptions variable from your Redux store. When you use useSelector to access data from the Redux store, it creates a new reference to the selected data every time the store updates. This means that the masterStatusOptions variable in your component will have a new reference whenever the Redux store is updated, causing your useEffect to run again and again in an infinite loop.

To fix this issue and prevent the infinite loop, try using the useMemo hook to memoize the masterStatusOptions variable and ensure that it only changes when the actual data inside it changes:

```
const masterStatusOptions = useSelector((state) => state.lookup.lookup); // assuming the default value is []

const statusOptions = useMemo(() => {
  return masterStatusOptions.filter((item) => item.priority !== 999)
}, [masterStatusOptions]);
```

Comment: masterStatusOptions will always have a new Array everytime state is updated. Even after using useMemo it will result in an infinite cycle because masterStatusOptions technically has changed its memory address and arrays are reference type in nature.

Comment: Is `lookupTypeData` creating a new array on every render? The redux state shouldn't be changing on every render.

Comment: Redux state even if it is not changing will return a new array which will have a different memory location and my useEffect will trigger and update the state(I have to use state because I want to refresh the dropdown list on UI)

Comment: so maybe combine `useMemo` and `useState`? put a memoized `statusOptions` in the useEffect  dependency array to watch it for changes?

Comment: `Redux state even if it is not changing will return a new array` If the state does not change, then redux will return the same array each time (by same array, i mean same memory location). It's not going to create new arrays for you. Now what you do once you get the state, that could create a new array, which is why i'm curious about what `lookupTypeData` is doing.

Comment: Everytime state changes it will trigger a rerender. Now when my component is rendered it fetches updated value from redux which will be a new array location. lookupTypeData is simply returning an array of objects with has label & value as the key.